# Error running Postman: timeout waiting for snap system profiles to get updated

Tags: 22.04

I was trying to run Postman by clicking on its icon but it seems like nothing happens so I gave it a try running `postman` command from terminal and got this error after a while.

```
internal error, please report: running "postman" failed: timeout waiting for snap system profiles to get updated
```

Any suggestion to diagnose the issue and fix it?

As a side note, OS version is Ubuntu 22.04 and Postman was working fine a few weeks ago.